# Executing a command on found file

Tags: email, command-line, find

I am not able to use exec with mail command on found files.

```
# find /etc/ -name my.cnf -mtime 0 -exec mail s.o@gmail.com
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Check if my.cnf has been changed in the last 24 hours

if yes, as in this case, send the file by email

if it has not been changed in the last 24 hours, do nothing.

**Update:**

The following shell script is working as expected, But I will like it all as one line command

```
#!/bin/sh
myfile=`find /etc/ -name my.cnf -mtime 0`
cat $myfile | mail -s "test" s.o@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need the \ next to the ; thus:

```
# find /etc/ -name my.cnf -mtime 0 -exec mail s.o@gmail.com \;
```

or how about:

```
# find /etc/ -name my.cnf -mtime 0 | xargs mail s.o@gmail.com
```

See http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/Find/using_exec_option_and_xargs_in_find.shtml for more information about executing commands with find

Comment: xargs does not return anything. -exec will send mail but with no message. A blank mail was sent.